# value that #each loops must be an array, controller passed

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I get these error messages upon loading the page:

```
Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array.
    You passed (generated snippets.index controller) ember-1.0.0.js:394

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'
```

Here is my template code:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="snippets/index">
  {{#each}}
    {{title}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

My 'Snippet' model is quite simple:

```
TSLibrary.Snippet = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});

TSLibrary.Snippet.FIXTURES = [{id: 1, title: 'Learn Ember.js'}];
```

My app and my router:

```
window.TSLibrary = Ember.Application.create();

TSLibrary.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

// ---

TSLibrary.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('snippets', { path: '/' }, function () {
  });
});

TSLibrary.SnippetsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    // My guess is that this does not return the expected array
    //
    // This logs 'Class {toString: function, constructor: function, reason: null, isPending: undefined, isSettled: undefined…}'

    console.log(this.store.find('snippet'));
    return this.store.find('snippet');
  }
});
```

So my guess is that `this.store.find('snippet')` is not returning the right data.
I've also installed the Ember debug extension in Chrome and it shows me all the right data in my model.

Ember version: 1.0.0
Ember Data version: `v1.0.0-beta.1-140-ga51f29c a51f29c (2013-09-07 16:34:55 -0700)`
Handlebars version: 1.0.0
jQuery version: 1.10.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TSLibrary.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('snippets', { path: '/' }, function () {
  });
});
```

This way creates the 'snippets.index' path, which requires a Route called SnippetsIndexRoute.

```
TSLibrary.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('snippets', { path: '/' });
});
```

This one is just 'snippets', which correctly uses the SnippetsRoute that you have defined.

Comment: I've just come across my own question again. It seems that I didn't get notified of your post. Anyway, welcome to StackOverflow and have your first accepted answer :) Thanks.

Comment: Had exactly this problem, was as simple as adding the word 'Index' into my camel-cased Route name. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by accident, now:

```
TSLibrary.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('snippets', { path: '/' }, function () {
  });
});
```

has to be

```
TSLibrary.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('snippets', { path: '/' });
});
```